# JWT implemented api not called from another web application while working on swagger

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have created web Api in .NET core 6.0 using JWT authentication.
It is working fine while call from swagger but if I call from another web application it gives unauthorized error 401.
Can anybody help me for this.
Issuer and audience is false in JWT token creation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: From your description, You Api seems ok. How do you send request with token? Do you add token into request header correctly? Please provide related code.

Comment: @XinranShen Shared code for the same